# jquery populate iframe field from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Sorry for the garbled code. After working thru it with alert and console.log, I realized that the

```
var username = $('#username').value = response2;
```

will populate jquery field programatically.

```
$('#signup-button').click(function() {  
    callTheJsonp();
});

function callTheJsonp()
{    
    // the url of the script where we send the asynchronous call
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/ajax1.php?callback=parseRequest";
    // create a new script element
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    // set the src attribute to that url
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    // insert the script in out page
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
}


function parseRequest(response){
    var response1 = response;       
          var re1='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
          var re2='([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})';    // Email Address 1

          var p = new RegExp(re1+re2,["i"]);
          var m = p.exec(response1);
          if (m != null)
          {
              var response2=m[1];
            //  document.write(""+email1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+"");
                myFunction(response2); //email address from parent without json encode
          }


    try // try to output this to the javascript console
    {

        console.log(response2);
    }
    catch(an_exception) // alert for the users that don't have a javascript console
    {
        alert('product id ' + response.item_id + ': quantity = ' + response.quantity + ' & price = ' + response.price);
    }

}
function myFunction(response2){//how would I populate the jquery objects with the value of response2, just substituting the varaible values breaks the code. 
    var username = $('#username').val().trim();
    var emailAddress = $('#emailAddress').val().trim();
    var password1 = $('#password1').val().trim();
    var password2 = $('#password2').val().trim();
    var postJson = {username: username,
        password1: password1,
        password2: password2};
    if (emailAddress) {
        postJson.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
    $('#spinner-container').append('<div id="spinner"><img src="/static/images/progress-spinner.gif" alt="in progress"/></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
    url: '/signup/',
    data: JSON.stringify(postJson),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = '/' + username + '/designs';
        },
    error: function(response) {
            SS.render_errors(JSON.parse(response.responseText));
            $('#spinner').remove();
        }
    });
        return false;
    }
});
```

at the line:

```
function myFunction(response2){
```

I want to populate the jquery fields with the response2 value which is a json object stripped into a string. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, shouldnt `$('#username').value` be changed to either `$('#username').val()` or `$('#username')[0].value` / `$('#username').get(0).value` ? And what type of data would `http://localhost:8888/ajax1.php?callback=parseRequest` return? Sounds like you should make a nested ajax request, with the first call to `http://localhost:8888/ajax1.php?callback=parseRequest`